# ASP.NET MVC 4 Default template has a different syntax for logout in _LoginPartial.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 for the first time, so I started with the default template.

In the _LoginPartial.cshmtl for Log off link I found the below code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}
```

I was expecting a code like the one below, which I have been using in MVC 3.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account")
```

Please can someone help me understand as to why this is necessary, and its advantages if any. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no big difference. MVC4 uses a HTML-form to logout, which is submitted via the javascript.

The advantage is that the new way (with the form) uses javascript to submit the form, which is why the page does not have to reload.

Comment: The page will have to reload if he form is posted back

Comment: Advantage? Of course if you don't have JavaScript enabled you can't log off! It should at least have a noscript tag with a non-javascript logoff for users without JavaScript enabled.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The reason it uses a form is to use the anti-forgery token as others have suggested which prevents "malicious" sites from being able to log you out by tricking you into clicking a link to the logout page.

Comment: The answer is incorrect. non-indempotent actions should be POST. extensions that cache your page may as well log out. Unfortunatelly the implementation by MVC 4 team is really bad.

Comment: How can I redirect to the login page ?

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the new syntax is that it follows a more RESTful syntax. By logging out you are changing a state on the user (hence the POST action).

Answer (score 2):

While making MVC 4 restful, the default template doesn't allow users with JavaScript disabled a way to log out. Here is the fix for that problem.

Note I also blogged about this issue here: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/09/cannot-log-out-of-aspnet-mvc4-without-javascript

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a id="logout" href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()" style="display:none">Log Off</a>
    <script>
        //<!--
        var l = document.getElementById('logout');
        if (typeof(l) != 'undefined' && l != null)
            l.style.display = "inline";
        //-->
    </script>
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="Log Off" />
    </noscript>
}
```

Basically, it falls back to a submit button rather than a link when JavaScript is not available. We still use a POST in all cases.

One other small problem - the CSS for the template makes the button look different than a link. Here is the fix for the CSS to style the logout button so it looks the same as the other "buttons" that are actually anchor tags.

```
/* drop this in just above "info and errors" */

#logoutForm input[type="submit"],
#logoutForm input[type="button"],
#logoutForm button
{
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: -4px 3px -4px 10px;
    padding: 2px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    outline: medium none;
}


/* for mobile styles - you need to drop this one in right after the other 
#login styles in the mobile block (near the bottom of the file) */

#login input[type="submit"],
#login input[type="button"],
#login button
{
    background: none;
    color: #999;
    border: none;
    border: 0px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: -4px 3px -4px 6px;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: inherit;
    outline: medium none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the only reason they used JavaScript here is because the css style of a submit button wouldn't have matched the css style of the "login" button which is an anchor tag created by the HTML helper with this code:

`@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })`.

The following will create the exact same behavior in the app:

`<input type="submit" value="Log Off" />`

but it looks horrible.

Of course they can't use the HTML helper ActionLink for the log off button anymore because this is a form that needs to be POSTed so that the AntiForgeryToken can be validated.

So, they needed the following:

1. An anchor tag for the log off link so that it will style the same as the log in link.
2. A button that can submit the form so that the AntiForgeryToken can be validated.

Hench an anchor tag that triggers a form postback via the explicit .submit() JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

"The advantage is that the new way (with the form) uses javascript to submit the form, which is why the page does not have to reload" ... (user1797792)

This is completely untrue as Html.BeginForm always triggers postback, Ajax.BeginForm is the async form helper that does not trigger post back

I prefer the old action link style as does not mess up css but from reviewing the function, it appears the actionlink has been replaced with form so that a AntiForgeryToken can be included in the request and would prevent cross site scripting blocking you out of your own account or something along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnContinueClick() {
    debugger
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("BIAssessmentTest", "BI")',
        type: 'Post',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            window.location.href = '@Url.Action("BIAssessQuestions", "BI")';
        },

        error: function (err) {
             debugger
            alert("hi");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: were you trying to answer the question...?

Comment: Please provide *context* to the answer, by explaining *how* and *why* the code works. Code-only answers are *valid* (if they address the question's problem), but are *not recommended*.