# ASP.NET MVC 4 form cannot logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views, logout

I have been fiddling around with the _Layout and _PartialLayouts of the default MVC 4 templates and suddenly the 'Logout' feature in the '_PartialLogin' doc has stopeed working.

The code is:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>
<p>Hello, @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Log off</a>
}</p>
</text>
}
```

Could it be possible that the javascript has been disabled unintentionally somehow. Am I missing some script tags maybe? Or is it something in the previous class where I called the _PartialLogin from??

Comment: run it in firefox with error console on and see if there is a javascript error preventing proper execution

Comment: does the controller gets called?

Comment: why are you doing this as a form

Comment: @DanielA.White: The default template does that, the user didn't write it.  There's some brief discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602269/asp-net-mvc-4-default-template-has-a-different-syntax-for-logout-in-loginpartia  Basically the ASP.NET MVC designers wanted it to be a POST action.

Comment: Thanks all
@mikey Is it possible to do it in chrome

Comment: @thefiloe I put a breakpoint in the controller and no it is not calling the logout method as the href is javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit(). But I dont understand because this section is the exact default generated code

Comment: The code you posted is working, in fact is the same that is being generatet automatically. You must have changed something in some other files.

Comment: @Tomek I know, thats the weird thing... so any pointers where to check?

Comment: @DanielA.White Because logging out a user should be done with a POST request

Comment: I even change it to `@Html.ActionLink("Log off", "LogOff", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })` and the redirect does not work. Is it because I am calling the _LoginPartial.cshtml in the _NavBar.cshtml which is being called from the _Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem...

You cannot put the javascript text in a `<form>` tag. It will not work as the bootstrap messes with it then.

It doesnt matter how many times you call the partialLayouts within eachother - just be careful which tags you embed the javascript in